# Alarm Activity does not launch when screen is off

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an alarm app with the `Intent` of launching and displaying an `Activity` when the alarm fires, even if the device screen is off. The app is targeting SDK 16+.
I can confirm through custom logging that the `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` is firing on time, and this in turn launches an `AlarmActivity`. Through custom logging the `AlarmActivity` is not luanching at the right time. Instead it either launches late or when the screen is turned on again by the user.

I am at a loss as to why this is happening. I have tried multiple solutions from other similar problems posted on SO.

Do you have any suggestions as to my issue? Thank you for any help!
See code below for `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`, `AlarmActivity`, and `AndroidManifest`.

I am testing on the following devices:
Samsung Galaxy II, Android 4.1.2, API 16 - (This is the worst at never triggering the AlarmActivity or waiting until the screen is turned on.)
LG Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, API 23
LG Harmony, Android 7.0, API 24

### AndroidManifest

```
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".view.AlarmActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".view.TimerActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".view.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 

        <!-- Register the BroadcastReceiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:name=".TimerBroadcastReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### AlarmBroadcastReceiver

```
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {

        // ***** CUSTOM LOGGING HERE *****
        // This code logs at the correct alarm time

        val newIntent = Intent(context, AlarmActivity::class.java)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context, newIntent, null)
    }

}
```

### AlarmActivity

```
class AlarmActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(com.devbygc.toddlertimer.R.layout.activity_alarm)

        // ***** CUSTOM LOGGING HERE *****
        // This code does NOT log until either
        // - user turns on the devices screen
        // - some lapse in time making the alarm "late" by 1 min to 1+ 

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            val k = this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
            k.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating Google's own codebase for their previous alarm - [AlarmClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock) - I figured out how to answer this issue using WakeLock.
The `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` acquires a partial wakelock in `onReceive()`. This is then released in the `onDestroy()` of my `AlarmActivity`.
A new class, `AlertWakeLock`, handles all the wakelock functionality.
There were no changes to the manifest, see original question for permissions.
This code has no successfully triggered the alarm on multiple devices with multiple tests with downtimes of 12+ hours.

To give credit I still found WindSekirun code helpful and suggest considering it if you find you have a similar problem.

See code below:

### AlarmBroadcastReceiver

```
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) 

        AlertWakeLock.acquireWakeLock(context)

        val newIntent = Intent(context, AlarmActivity::class.java)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context, newIntent, null)
    }

}
```

### AlarmActivity

```
class AlarmActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        AlertWakeLock.releaseWakeLock()
    }

}
```

### AlertWakeLock

```
class AlertWakeLock {

    companion object {

        private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null

        fun acquireWakeLock(context: Context) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Acquiring cpu wake lock")
            if (wakeLock != null) {
                return
            }

            val pm = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager

            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK or
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or
                    PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "ToddlerTimer:WakeLock"
            )
            wakeLock!!.acquire()
        }

        fun releaseWakeLock() {
            Log.d(TAG,"Releasing cpu wake lock")
            if (wakeLock != null) {
                wakeLock!!.release()
                wakeLock = null
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my medicine reminder project.

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

**Code**

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun Activity.setTurnScreenOnLock() {
    val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as? KeyguardManager?
    when {
        android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27 -> {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
            keyguardManager?.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
        }
        android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 26 -> {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
            keyguardManager?.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
        }
        else -> {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
        }
    }

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
}
```

**Usages** (It's Java, acutally.)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.setTurnScreenOnLock(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I have applied your code and tested multiple times on all devices. The outcome is interesting.
The Nexus 5 is displaying the `AlarmActivity` accurately.
The LG Harmony and Samsung Galaxy are not displaying the `AlarmActivity` until user turns on the screen.
Any thoughts on why?

Comment: First, you should throw Galaxy II because nowadays we have S10. (it almost 8 years). Second, I can check this code in almost LG flagship device such as G3~G7, so I think code hasn't any problem.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about throwing away the Galaxy II, however my app is geared especially for older devices. :/

Comment: Hmm... If so, my answer will not be so helpful. In my case, this was not a problem because I targeted the latest devices. (It has been around for more than five months.)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for it to actually reflect. Thank you for your time and help!