# Turn on phone screen when AlarmManager fires and BroadCastReceiver onReceive is triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am implementing a custom alarm with some logic behind it. When the alarm fires and the Broadcast receiver run the onReceive, the app starts a new activity for vibration and ringtone deactivation. 
Because is an alarm, I want it to fires also when the phone is locked, and in sleep mode as well. 
The alarm fires properly, even if the phone is in sleep mode. However, when I test the app on my smartphone (not just mine, but also my brother one), if the screen is OFF, it is not turned ON. On the contrary, the system works properly on the simulator with a pixel2 and android 9.
Below the receiver, and the manifest for the receiver and the app to disable the vibration and the tone ring.

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val extras = intent?.getExtras()
        val alarmId = intent?.getIntExtra("alarmId",-1)

        if(alarmId != null){
            val ta = MemoryManager.getAlarmWithId(alarmId.toInt())
            if(ta != null && ta!!.isSet){
                startAlarmActivity(context,alarmId)
            }
        }
    }
}

<activity
    android:name=".AlarmDeactivation"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_deactivation"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:turnScreenOn="true">
</activity>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
</receiver>
```

And this how I set the alarm.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
     alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
 }
 else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
     alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
 } 
 else{
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
 }
```

How can I let the app to turn on the screen when the alarm fires?

Thanks to all.

**EDIT**

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877390/alarm-activity-does-not-launch-when-screen-is-off), I tried to define a class where I implemented the powerManager WakeLock acquire and release, but without any changed.

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        val extras = intent?.getExtras()
        val alarmId = intent?.getIntExtra("alarmId",-1)

        AlertWakeLock.acquireWakeLock(context!!)

        if(alarmId != null){
            val ta = MemoryManager.getAlarmWithId(alarmId.toInt())
            if(ta != null && ta!!.isSet){
                startAlarmActivity(context,alarmId)
            }
        }
    }
}

class AlertWakeLock {

    companion object {

        private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null

        fun acquireWakeLock(context: Context) {
            if (wakeLock != null) {
                return
            }

            val pm = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager

            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK or
                        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or
                        PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "ToddlerTimer:WakeLock"
            )
            wakeLock!!.acquire()
        }

        fun releaseWakeLock() {
            if (wakeLock != null) {
                wakeLock!!.release()
                wakeLock = null
            }
        }
    }
}

class AlarmDeactivation : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            setContentView(R.layout.alarm_deactivation)
            val alarmId = intent.getIntExtra("ALARM_ID", -1)

            val ta = MemoryManager.getAlarmWithId(alarmId.toInt())

            val button: View = findViewById(R.id.saveButton)
            val afm = AlarmFeedbackManager(this)
            afm.play()

            button.setOnClickListener{
                MemoryManager.deSetAlarm(alarmId)
                MemoryManager.saveAlarmIntoMemory()

                afm.stop()

                val mCtx = GlobalApplication.appContext
                val intent = Intent(mCtx, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

                mCtx?.startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            var i = e
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        AlertWakeLock.releaseWakeLock()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` OR `RTC_WAKEUP` flags when setting up the `AlarmManager`?

Comment: @ICantC, I am using RTC_WAKEUP. I edited the post for the code